# How to implement vertical recycler view which shows only one item at a time and next item when swiping up?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was working on a project. I want to implement a vertical recyclerview which shows only one item at a time. And when swiping up the card it will show the next cardview. Just like Inshorts new app or Google primer

Comment: You should use `ViewPager2` to do it easily. Here is a documentation when it talks about vertical ViewPager : https://blog.usejournal.com/early-introduction-of-viewpager2-ff38c60d2169